# Pass Parameter to twigExtension

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like ot pass a parameter from twig to an twig extension.

Actually, the parameter or twig-Variable looks like

```
{{ myparameter }}
```

and my extension-call looks like this:

```
{{ 'name'|myextension()}}
```

If I try to pass the parameter like

```
{{ 'name'|myextension(myparameter)}}
```

it won't work, similar to

```
{{ 'name'|myextension({{myparameter}})}}
```

How can I pass my parameter? I'm stucking

Thank you in advance

Comment: `{{ 'name'|myextension(myparameter)}}` should be working. Can you show the code of your extension ?

Comment: No it won't. in my case its the Parameter from parameters.yml and is like {{ http_shared_image_dir }}.  If I use it the way you (and also I ) thought, it ends up in an error ... Uhm.. btw. After clearing the Cache it works!!! How is that possible :(

Comment: Well, yes, clearing the cache is always a must do when something doesn't work